# MySQL Alias Help ERROR 1054 (42S22)

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I will keep this brief and simple. I want to perform this query:

```
mysql> SELECT ORDER_NUM, NUM_ORDERED * QUOTED_PRICE AS TOTAL_AMOUNT
    -> FROM ORDER_LINE
    -> WHERE TOTAL_AMOUNT > '1000'
    -> ORDER BY ORDER_NUM;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'TOTAL_AMOUNT' in 'where clause'
```

I'm sure it's something simple but I don't understand why this wont work using the alias TOTAL_AMOUNT. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
mysql> SELECT ORDER_NUM, NUM_ORDERED * QUOTED_PRICE AS TOTAL_AMOUNT
-> FROM ORDER_LINE
-> WHERE NUM_ORDERED * QUOTED_PRICE > '1000'
-> ORDER BY ORDER_NUM;
```

Comment: Ahh yes thank you for your swift response! I don't know why I just didn't do this in the first place!

Comment: in where clause dont do the aliaces , nice it fixed your problem !

Answer (score 0):

Check if that asterisk is not causing you problems or if you are missing a comma and if that does not work, enclose the alias between grave accent simbols like this:

```
... QUOTED_PRICE AS `TOTAL_AMOUNT`...
```

Comment: Thanks for the post PachinSV! I did what echo_me said to do and it worked just how I wanted it to! I'm still new to SQL so it's hard to remember all the rules but I'll get the hang of it soon I'm sure. Again thanks for the help!